# SQLITE - Compare count values on 2 tables with same schema

Tags: sqlite, count

i am quite new in sqlite.

I have 2 tables (tableA, tableB) with the exact same schema.

```
id | CAT | country
```

They track the number of items per country on a special SW release

I would like to create a query that compares the count of rows per country on tableA and tableB where CAT = "AAA" on a single result like:

```
COUNTRY |count_tableA |count_tableB|
ARG     |12           |16          |
BRA     |23           |33          |
```

I can achieve it in separate tables but not in a single one.
Seperate table example:

```
select COUNTRY, count(*) as count_tableA from tableA WHERE CAT ="AAA" GROUP BY COUNTRY
select COUNTRY, count(*) as count_tableB from tableB WHERE CAT ="AAA" GROUP BY COUNTRY
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is use conditional aggregation on the `UNION` of the 2 tables:

```
select country, 
       sum(tablename = 'a') count_tableA,
       sum(tablename = 'b') count_tableB
from (
  select 'a' tablename, id, cat, country from tableA
  union all
  select 'b' tablename, id, cat, country from tableB
)
where cat = 'AAA'
group by country
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. If i have both tables in the same DB no problem at all.

Do you know if it is possible to run the same query in tables in different DB (assuming i am attaching the DB to compare)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WITH` and `COUNT`:

```
with t1 as (select country, count(*) as c1 from tableA where cat = 'AAA' group by country), 
t2 as (select country, count(*) as c1 from tableB where cat = 'AAA' group by country)
select a1.country, 
   ifnull((select t1.c1 from t1 where t1.country = a1.country), 0) as count_tableA, 
   ifnull((select t2.c1 from t2 where t2.country = a1.country), 0) as count_tableB from (
     select distinct country from tableA where cat = 'AAA'
     union
     select distinct country from tableB where cat = 'AAA'
   ) a1
group by country
```

Comment: This will not work in case a country exists in only 1 table.

Comment: Also Works fine but @forpas solution was faster! but thanks anyway

Comment: @paulojfonseca then why did you accept this answer?

Comment: because i don't know how this works :) and thought i could accept both!!!